# Missing php5-fpm after PHP5.5 upgrade

Tags: php, nginx, php-fpm

I just updated my PHP on Ubuntu 12.04

[image: Capture]

Now, with all weirdness, I did a simple `phpinfo.php` on my server, then this **502 Bad Gateway** starts appearing. I check the `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` nginx configuration file, and it seems that everything is normal:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
                # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
                # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
        }

        location /doc/ {
                alias /usr/share/doc/;
                autoindex on;
                allow 127.0.0.1;
                allow ::1;
                deny all;
        }

        # Only for nginx-naxsi used with nginx-naxsi-ui : process denied requests
        #location /RequestDenied {
        #       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        #}

        #error_page 404 /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        #error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        #location = /50x.html {
        #       root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

                # With php5-cgi alone:
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                # With php5-fpm:
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

Not sure what the problem is, my PHP is fine before I did that upgrade.

**EDIT**

Just noticed, I go to the directory of `/var/run/php5-fpm.sock` but did not see any `php5-fpm.sock` in there. Is this the cause?

Comment: Check if php-fpm service is up and running.

Comment: Is PHP-FPM actually running (and listening on the specified port)? (`netstat -pant | grep php`). If not restart it (stop it first if needed)

Comment: I tried doing `sudo service php5-fpm start` but nothing happens, same to `sudo service php5-fpm stop` and `sudo service php5-fpm restart`. Am I doing it right?

Comment: @cyberx86 - Did this `sudo netstat -pant | grep php` but results to no output.

Comment: @LeandroGarcia: Probably not running in that case (you can try again with just `sudo netstat -pant` in case the process has a different name); you can cross check with `ps -ef | grep php`. If it is running, but not listening, kill the running process(es). Presuming that php5-fpm is the service name (probably is), the (re)start/stop syntax is correct. Things to check include: your php-fpm logs (`/var/log/php-fpm.log` or similar) and what your init script is doing.

Comment: @cyberx86 - `sudo netstat -pant` shows no relevance for php5-fpm. `ps -ef | grep php` shows `user1 12008  4395  0 01:32 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto php` php is in red color. While `/var/log/php-fpm.log` just contains error log file _re-opened, Finishing..., exiting, bye bye!_

Comment: So, (as expected) php-fpm isn't running - you need to start it. There should be an init script in `/etc/init.d` (probably `/etc/init.d/php5-fpm`). You can run it directly (/etc/init.d/php5-fpm start) (but the result should be the same as running `service ...`. If it doesn't start php-fpm for you, open the file, and see if you can redirect any errors to the console (e.g removing any references to /dev/null);

Comment: Just to address your update (the netstat command was actually for php-fpm listening on a port (which yours isn't - didn't see that line was commented out in your config) - but, your problem is that php-fpm isn't even running; your .sock file should be recreated once you start php-fpm.

Comment: @cyberx86 - Did this `/etc/init.d/php5-fpm start` but no avail. I don't quite understand what you mean by _if you can redirect any errors to the console (e.g removing any references to /dev/null)_.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9887/discussion-between-cyberx86-and-leandro-garcia)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that PHP-FPM is running:

```
ps -ef | grep php
```

In your case, it wasn't running.
Check that it is installed:

```
dpkg -s php5-fpm
```

In your case, the package was marked as 'Status: deinstall'.
The cause of this was that you upgraded PHP from a PPA ([ppa:ondrej/php5](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/php5)), which caused your original copy to be removed. You might have to reinstall any non-core packages to regain that functionality.

To add back php-fpm, you can run:

```
apt-get install php5-fpm
```

In your case, this failed with:

```
php5-fpm : Depends: libsystemd-daemon0 (>= 31) but it is not installable
```

Since the publisher of the PPA you used has another PPA ([ppa:ondrej/systemd](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/systemd)) that provides this package, install that to resolve the missing dependencies, and re-run the install.

Once complete, verify your install was successful and that php-fpm is running.

Comment: Thanks so much for the assistance you provided on chat! Huge thanks!